# error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrate FCM Notification in app.I got error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types.
In NotificationCompat constructor I only pass one parameter.If I pass two parameter I got above error.

I got FCM Token and Message Body But FCM not display on Notification Bar when I am comment below code in build.gradle then I pass two parameter inside NotificationCompat constructor but I got error other java  files like can not resolved getSupportManger,getActionBar(class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found)please check below code

> ```
>     > buildscript {
>     >     repositories {
>     >         google()
>     >         jcenter()
>     >     }
>     >     dependencies {  
>     >         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
>     >         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
>     >         classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
>     >     }} allprojects {
>     >     repositories {
>     >         google()
>     >         jcenter()
>     >     }} task clean(type: Delete) {    delete rootProject.buildDir } subprojects {
>     >     project.configurations.all {
>     >         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
>     >             if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
>     >                     && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
>     >                 details.useVersion "25.3.1"
>     >             }        }
>     >     } }
>     > 
>     > showNotification Method    public void showNotification(String
>     > title,String message){
>     >     NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"")
>     >             .setContentTitle("abc")
>     >             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_logo)
>     >             .setAutoCancel(true)
>     >             .setContentText(message);
>     >     NotificationManagerCompat manager= >NotificationManagerCompat.from(this,"MyNotification");//error here
>
> >manager.notify(999,notificationBuilder.build()); }
> ```

When I comment subProject part inside gradle file than I pass two parameter inside Notification Compact constructor but I got error in other java files like(class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found). I already pass one parameter inside Notification Compact constructor but I got fcm message but not display notification on notification bar so what should I do

Comment: where you call showNotification?

Comment: I create class and extends by FirebaseMessagingService